# C++ string array slice

Tags: c++, arrays, string

How would I split an inputted string such as "one two three four five" into an array.
currentyly I have this:

```
const int SIZE = 5;
string digit[SIZE];

cout << "Enter the five here:";
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    cout << i+1 << ")";
    getline(cin, digit[i]);
}
```

but as it stands, the user has to hit enter every time. How do I get it so when I call `digit[1]` for the example input above, I get `two`. Hopefully that makes sense, I would imagine there is some function to do this for you, but if there is really elementary way of doing it, that would probably benefit me best, I'm still learning. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read words separated by whitespace, you can take advantage of the fact that extracting a string from an input stream will stop at whitespace:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    cout << i+1 << ")";
    cin >> digit[i];
}
```

Comment: perfect - I don't know why that didn't occur to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to take all the 'five' in a single line you can do that also.
and then you can use `strtok()` to split the string into five strings.
see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: `strtok` is nasty though. The use of global state can bite you.

Comment: `strtok_r` and `strsep` are much better than common `strtok`

Answer (score 0):

You also may use `getline` function with 3 arguments. 3rd is delimiter.

```
 getline(cin, digit[i], ' ');
```

Of course, it isn't best way to read input from `cin`. But you can use such approach for splitting full string, which you've get from user.

Comment: that still takes place in the for loop correct? I tried it and the process stalls; it doesn't move on to the next task.